# How can I use .find to change the value of a value inside a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, nested

I am going to be using a concrete example for what I want to do, as I find this is the easiest way to make my point clear.

I would like to know how I could use the .find method to look for the student named "Frank" and turn his grade to "F", for example.

Here is what the nested array would look like in this example:

```
School data{ 
  :name => "School Name",
  :location => "NYC",
  :students => [ 
    {:name => "Steven", :grade => "B"},
    {:name=>"Bob", :grade => "F"},
    {:name => "Frank", :grade => "A"},
    {:name => "Silvia", :grade => "C"}
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, I almost fell for this. I can't in good conscience help you change your grades at school.  ;-)  Bueller? Bueller? Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
frank = data[:students].find { |s| s[:name] == 'Frank' }
frank[:grade] = 'F'
```

Consider using classes instead of nested `Hash`es and `Array`s.